# Can anyone suggest mantras for worshiping Mata Sita and Sri Radha Rani?

Tags: worship, mantras, sita, radha

I am looking for some mantras for chanting mantras specific to Sita and radha rani.

Comment: It is always recommended to worship Sita along with Sri Rama. Worshipping only one of them is not recommended. If worshipped both, results will be more fruitful.

Comment: @SreeCharan Agreed .... can you make that an answer, with those mantras ?

Comment: What if this man is a shaakta? Don't you know both goddesses are major deities of Shaktism? Whose shakti will the devi play?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is Gayatri Mantras for various deities mentioned [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Gayatri_mantras_of_Several_Gods). Gayatri mantra for Devi Radha is as follows:

> ॐ वृषभानुजायै विद्महे कृष्णप्रियायै धीमहि तन्नो राधा प्रचोदयात्॥
>   Om Vrishabhanujayai Vidhmahe
>
> Krishnapriyayai Dheemahi
>
> Thanno Radha Prachodayath.
>
> Om, Let me meditate on the daughter of Vrishabhanu,
>   Oh, darling of Krishna, give me higher intellect,
>   And let Radha illuminate my mind.

Gayatri mantra for Devi Sita is as follows:

> ॐ जनकनन्दिन्यै विद्महे भूमिजायै धीमहि तन्नः सीता प्रचोदयात्॥
>   Om Janaka Nandinyai Vidhmahe
>
> Bhumijayai Dheemahi
>
> Thannah Sita Prachodayath.
>
> Om, Let me meditate on the daughter of Janaka
>   Oh, daughter of earth, give me higher intellect,
>   And let Sita illuminate my mind.

Also there are some Stotras for Devi Sita and Devi Radha are present. There is [Radha Shoddasha Nama Stotram](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_radharani-sixteen_names.php) that is said to be from Brahma Vaivartha Purana.

> श्रीनारायण उवाच
>
> राधा रासेश्वरी रासवासिनी रसिकेश्वरी ।
>
> कृष्णप्राणाधिका कृष्णप्रिया कृष्णस्वरूपिणी ॥१॥
>
> Shriinaaraayanna Uvaaca
>
> Raadhaa Raaseshvarii Raasavaasinii Rasikeshvarii |
>
> Krssnnapraannaadhikaa Krssnnapriyaa Krssnnasvaruupinnii ||1||
>
> Sri Narayana said:
>
> 1.1: (The sixteen names of Radharani are) Radha, Raaseshwari, Raasavasini, Rasikeshwari, ...
>
> 1.2: ... Krishnapranadhika, Krishnapriya, Krishna Swarupini, ...
>
> कृष्णवामाङ्गसम्भूता परमानन्दरूपिणी ।
>
> कृष्णा वृन्दावनी वृन्दा वृन्दावनविनोदिनी ॥२॥
>
> Krssnnavaamaanggasambhuutaa Paramaanandaruupinnii |
>
> Krssnnaa Vrndaavanii Vrndaa Vrndaavanavinodinii ||2||
>
> (The sixteen names of Radharani continued)
>
> 2.1: ... Krishna Vamanga Sambhuta, Paramanandarupini, ...
>
> 2.2: ... Krishnaa, Vrindavani, Vrindaa, Vrindavana Vinodini,
>
> चन्द्रावली चन्द्रकान्ता शरच्चन्द्रप्रभानना ।
>
> नामान्येतानि साराणि तेषामभ्यन्तराणि च ॥३॥
>
> Candraavalii Candrakaantaa Sharaccandraprabhaananaa |
>
> Naamaany-Etaani Saaraanni Tessaam-Abhyantaraanni Ca ||3||
>
> (The sixteen names of Radharani continued)
>
> 3.1: ... Chandravali, Chandrakanta, Sharacchandra Prabhanana (Sharat Chandra Prabhanana),
>
> 3.2: These (sixteen) Names, which are the essence are included in those (thousand names),

24 more verses are there you may read in link. There is [Janaki stuti mentioned here](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_sita-janaki_stutih.php).

> जानकि त्वां नमस्यामि सर्वपापप्रणाशिनीम् ॥१॥
>
> Jaanaki Tvaam Namasyaami Sarva-Paapa-Prannaashiniim ||1||
>
> Meaning:
>
> (Hanumanji said:)
>   1.1: O Devi Janaki, I salute You; You are the destroyer of all Sins,
>
> दारिद्र्यरणसंहर्त्रीं भक्तानाभिष्टदायिनीम् ।
>
> विदेहराजतनयां राघवानन्दकारिणीम् ॥२॥
>
> Daaridrya-Ranna-Samhartriim Bhaktaana-Abhisstta-Daayiniim |
>
> Videha-Raaja-Tanayaam Raaghava-[A]ananda-Kaarinniim ||2||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 2.1: (I Salute You) You are the destroyer of Poverty (in the battle of life) and bestower of wishes of the Devotees,
>
> 2.2: (I Salute You) You are the daughter of Videha Raja (King Janaka), and cause of Joy of Raghava (Sri Rama),
>
> भूमेर्दुहितरं विद्यां नमामि प्रकृतिं शिवाम् ।
>
> पौलस्त्यैश्वर्यसंहत्रीं भक्ताभीष्टां सरस्वतीम् ॥३॥
>
> Bhuumer-Duhitaram Vidyaam Namaami Prakrtim Shivaam |
>
> Paulastya-[A]ishvarya-Samhatriim Bhakta-Abhiissttaam Sarasvatiim ||3||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 3.1: I Salute You, You are the daughter of the Earth and the embodiment of Knowledge; You are the Auspicious Prakriti,
>
> 3.2: (I Salute You) You are the destroyer of the Power and Supremacy of (oppressors like) Ravana, (and at the same time) fulfiller of the wishes of the Devotees; You are an embodiment of Saraswati,
>
> पतिव्रताधुरीणां त्वां नमामि जनकात्मजाम् ।
>
> अनुग्रहपरामृद्धिमनघां हरिवल्लभाम् ॥४॥
>
> Pativrataa-Dhuriinnaam Tvaam Namaami Janaka-[A]atmajaam |
>
> Anugraha-Paraam-Rddhim-Anaghaam Hari-Vallabhaam ||4||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 4.1: I Salute You, You are the best among Pativratas (Ideal Wife devoted to Husband), (and at the same time) the Soul of Janaka (Ideal Daughter devoted to Father),
>
> 4.2: (I Salute You) You are very Gracious (being Yourself the embodiment of) Riddhi (Lakshmi), (Pure and) Sinless, and extremely Beloved of Hari,
>
> आत्मविद्यां त्रयीरूपामुमारूपां नमाम्यहम् ।
>
> प्रसादाभिमुखीं लक्ष्मीं क्षीराब्धितनयां शुभाम् ॥५॥
>
> Aatma-Vidyaam Trayii-Ruupaam-Umaa-Ruupaam Namaamyaham |
>
> Prasaada-Abhimukhiim Lakssmiim Kssiira-Abdhi-Tanayaam Shubhaam ||5||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 5.1: I Salute You, You are the embodiment of Atma Vidya, mentioned in the Three Vedas (Manifesting its Inner Beauty in Life); You are of the nature of Devi Uma,
>
> 5.2: (I Salute You) You are the Auspicious Lakshmi, the daughter of the Milky Ocean, and always intent on bestowing Grace (to the Devotees),
>
> नमामि चन्द्रभगिनीं सीतां सर्वाङ्गसुन्दरीम् ।
>
> नमामि धर्मनिलयां करुणां वेदमातरम् ॥६॥
>
> Namaami Candra-Bhaginiim Siitaam Sarva-Angga-Sundariim |
>
> Namaami Dharma-Nilayaam Karunnaam Veda-Maataram ||6||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 6.1: I Salute You, You are like the sister of Chandra (in Beauty), You are Sita Who is Beautiful in Her entirety,
>
> 6.2: (I Salute You) You are an Abode of Dharma, full of Compassion and the Mother of Vedas,
>
> पद्मालयां पद्महस्तां विष्णुवक्षःस्थलालयाम् ।
>
> नमामि चन्द्रनिलयां सीतां चन्द्रनिभाननाम् ॥७॥
>
> Padma-[A]alayaam Padma-Hastaam Vissnnu-Vakssah-Sthala-[A]alayaam |
>
> Namaami Candra-Nilayaam Siitaam Candra-Nibha-[A]ananaam ||7||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 7.1: (I Salute You) (You as Devi Lakshmi) Abide in Lotus, hold Lotus in Your Hands, and always reside in the Heart of Sri Vishnu,
>
> 7.2: I Salute You, You reside in Chandra Mandala, You are Sita Whose Face resembles the Moon,
>
> आह्लादरूपिणीं सिद्धिं शिवां शिवकरीं सतीम् ।
>
> नमामि विश्वजननीं रामचन्द्रेष्टवल्लभाम् ।
>
> सीतां सर्वानवद्याङ्गीं भजामि सततं हृदा ॥८॥
>
> Aahlaada-Ruupinniim Siddhim Shivaam Shivakariim Satiim |
>
> Namaami Vishva-Jananiim Raamacandre[a-I]sstta-Vallabhaam |
>
> Siitaam Sarvaan-Avadya-Anggiim Bhajaami Satatam Hrdaa ||8||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 8.1: (I Salute You) Your Form gives Joy to all, You are the Sati (Devoted Wife) Whose presence is Auspicious and confers Siddhi and Liberation,
>
> 8.2: I Salute the Mother of the Universe, Who is the Beloved of Ramachandra,
>
> 8.3: I always Worship You in my Heart, O Mother Sita, You are Beautiful in entirety, the Beauty which cannot be expressed in words.

Answer (score 0):

Its here in aadi ramayan aka bhusundi ramayan sita sahasranama stotram
Starting lines:-

**Om sahajanandini sita janki radhika rati.
Rukmini Kamala kanta kantih kamallochanah**

[image]

Comment: Sir but OP is asking about mantras and not stotras.

Comment: Ist line of stotra is a mantra that contains both maa sita and radha rani